# Unable to boot Ubuntu 22.04 in a DELL precision T1700

Tags: dell, 22.04

I'm quite frustrated trying to make ubuntu 22.04 work in my dell precision t1700 workstation.

As always, Windows 10 Pro works perfectly fine.
Also, FreeBSD 13 works very well.

Problem: ubuntu 22.04 installation is done without any issues. The installation goes successfully and then, after reboot to start the OS the first time, I get the following error message:

The error message is:

```
Unexpected return from initial read: Device Error, buffersize 0
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Device Error
start_image() returned Device Error
```

I tried to fix the boot using `boot-repair` tool without any success. Here's the log for the boot repair:

[boot-repair-log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/x2nnqkzS9f/)

I tried different configurations from BIOS and UEFI, no success at all.
Here is what I tried already:

[How to Install Ubuntu Developer Edition 14.04 on a Dell PC Configured for the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) BIOS](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-vn/000141125/xps-13-9343-how-to-install-ubuntu-developer-edition-14-04-on-a-dell-pc-configured-for-the-unified-extensible-firmware-interface-uefi-bios)

My BIOS configuration is exactly as explained in this link above. I played with this many ways, including:

- enable/disable secure boot
- enable/disable legacy option ROMs
- activate/deactivate TPM security
- clear TPM security

so far, no luck, any ideas?

thank you very much ^^,
@Ross

Comment: Can you try installing Ubuntu to some drive other than the internal hard drive? You can boot the installation ISO, then plug in a blank flash drive and install to it instead. This will help rule out the possibility of internal drive failure.

Comment: @arraybolt3 this desktop has 2 SSD, I tried to install on both of them, one I bought 2 days ago, the other one that it was running windows just fine, same thing. I'll install in one external disk here to test, let's see.

Comment: Hmm. My best guess then is that the EFI shim isn't able to load GRUB. Can you try doing this: 1. Disable secure boot. 2. When booting the laptop, get into the boot menu. 3. Once you're into the boot menu, select "Boot From File" or something like that. 4. Navigate through the folders until you find "grubx64.efi" and select it.

Comment: Do not know zfs. Thought most used ext4 for boot partition & then zfs for data. But it looks like it works with some special grub settings: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2470405&page=8&p=14083021#post14083021 Linus - Do not use ZFS on Linux
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linus-Says-No-To-ZFS-Linux &
https://linux.slashdot.org/story/20/01/19/0059251/what-linus-torvalds-gets-wrong-about-zfs#comments

Comment: @ArrayBolt3, I discovered what happened. there's some incompatibility with the caddy driver where the ubuntu was installed. so, to solve the problem, I moved the SSD with Windows 10 Pro to the caddy driver and I connected the SSD with Ubuntu 22.04 directly to the sata port. Weird, I'd say. BTW, here's the caddy driver that I have: [https://redtech.lk/product/laptop-secondary-hard-drive-caddy-optical-drive-replacement/](Laptop Secondary Hard Drive Caddy [Optical Drive Replacement]).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ArrayBolt3 and @oldfred, I discovered what happened.

There's some incompatibility with the caddy driver where the ubuntu was installed. so, to solve the problem, I moved the SSD with Windows 10 Pro to the caddy driver and I connected the SSD with Ubuntu 22.04 directly to the sata port. Weird, I'd say. BTW, here's the caddy driver that I have: [Laptop Secondary Hard Drive Caddy [Optical Drive Replacement]](https://redtech.lk/product/laptop-secondary-hard-drive-caddy-optical-drive-replacement/).

The most strange part is, Ubuntu only cannot boot from the SSD in the caddy driver. Everything else works perfectly fine. I read some dell forums where people said that they had similar problems and then, I found this solution.

Problem solved. Thank you ^^